# Does ngView leak memory, retain DOM nodes in memory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, memory-leaks

### Memory leak in Angular:

The angularjs website has a step-by-step tutorial for getting started.  I'm looking at section 7 entitled “[Routing & Multiple Views](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07)”

There is a [demo app](http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-7/app/) attached to the tutorial, and you can see what a view-router setup looks like.

I am seeing what looks like memory leak, DOM node escalation, when I click to view an entry, and then click 'back' to return to the main page.  Here's a [screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lFVS.png) of the Chrome Canary "timeline" performance, as I click back and forth between main page and individual 'phone' pages.

[image]

I have the same problem in my own app.

I have been tearing my hair out trying to get it to release DOM elements once ngView has navigated away from a given route.  But now I see Angular's baseline demo app has the same problem -- detached DOM nodes stay in memory.  I can look at them in the [Heap Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRewW.png), but it doesn't give me insight into how to prevent them.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried it in the regular release of Chrome? I don't notice the growth in nodes there, and memory release periodically.

Comment: Interesting.  You're right.  Here's the (non-canary) Chrome [timeline](http://i.imgur.com/zC3SRFb.png) for 2 minutes of forward-back clicking through pages.  It looks like the browser runs garbage collection every 45 seconds.

Comment: In your image, the baseline isn't being reset.  It continues to grow in spite of garbage collection.  The problem still exists maybe?

Comment: I don't think there's a leak.  Here's one more [timeline](http://i.imgur.com/UOleqKD.png) showing 4+ minutes of back-and-forth navigation, where you can see more clearly that the low point reset remains consistent -- once garbage collection kicks in, we return to 26 listeners and 1730 nodes